# type 'char *' but argument has type 'char' also data not printing to file

Tags: c, printf, compiler-warnings

Hey everyone I am getting a warning on Line 51 "format specifies type 'char*' but argument has type 'char'. I am having an very hard time seeing where to fix this error. Also, My program is failing to print the new sorted data to my output file. How can I chane my organization to achieve that?

```
1    #include <stdio.h>
2    #include <stdlib.h>
3    #include <string.h>
4    #include <limits.h>
5    
6    int main(void) {
7       const int N=200;
8       char name[N], symbol[N];
9       char printed[N];
10      int atomicNumber[N], n, i, p, j, min;
11      double atomicWeight[N];
12      FILE *fi;
13      FILE *fo;
14    
15      fi=fopen("Lab6Elements.txt", "r");
16      if(fi==NULL) {
17          printf("Error opening file.\n");
18          return EXIT_FAILURE;
19      }
20      while(1){
21          n=0;
22          if(EOF == fscanf(fi,"%s%s%d%lf", &name[n], &symbol[n], &atomicNumber[n], &atomicWeight[n])) break; 
23    
24          printed[n]=0;
25          n++;
26          }
27    
28      fo=fopen("OutputData.txt", "w");
29          fprintf(fo, "\n%-15s%4s%5s%10s\n", "Element","Symb","No.","Weight");
30          for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
31              min = INT_MAX;
32    
33              for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
34    
35                  if(!printed[j] && atomicNumber[j]<min){
36                      min = atomicNumber[j];
37                      p = j;
38    
39                  }
40    
41                  fprintf(fo,"%-15s%-4s%5d%10.4lf\n", name[p], symbol[p], atomicNumber[p], atomicWeight[p]);
42    
43                                      printed[p] = 1;
44              }
45    
46          }
47          return EXIT_SUCCESS;
48      }
```

Comment: Your program has no line 51, seeing as you included line numbers...

Comment: Maybe post the code you compiled when you got that error, instead of some other code...

Comment: sorry for the typo

Comment: If there was a typo please edit your post and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be in line 41. You claimed to print c-strings (type `char *`) with `%s` formats but gave `char` parameters, i.e. `name[p]` and `symbol[p]`. Either choose to print a single `char` with `%c` or give `name` and `symbol` as parameters.

Comment: I want to change the order in which the lines are printed from my input file. There is a name and symbol which for each element on each line. I want to print the line corresponding to the p value. Each line is comprised of the name of an element, their symbol which is comprised of <=4 letters, atomic number, and atomic weight.

Answer (score 0):

In your `fprintf` you have as part of the format string a few `%s` specifiers, which will print a string, but as corresponding parameter there is e.g. `name[p]`, which is a single character. You are lucky that your compiler complains.

In your `fscanf` you make the same mistake of reading a string with `%s` and assigning that to a char, although `&name[n]` will yield an address where the string is placed, but you mean just `name`.

---

Though your original question is answered, I see a serious poblem in your code: you allocate an array of 200 characters but you want to read in 200 strings!
You could do:

```
char name[200][30]; // array of 200 strings of at most 30 characters
```

Comment: I want to change the order in which the lines are printed from my input file. There is a name and symbol which for each element on each line. I want to print the line corresponding to the p value. Each line is comprised of the name of an element, their symbol which is comprised of <=4 letters, atomic number, and atomic weight.

Comment: Also I am still getting no output into my output file

Comment: You need to add `fclose(fo);` to close the output file once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

There are no line 51 in example, but I think this about line 41 fprintf.

Arguments name[p] and symbol[p] has type 'char', but for compile must be 'char*', simplest replace it by (name + p) and (symbol + p) respective, which has 'char*' type, this must help.